# Why is nothing happening when I run my program?

Tags: java

When I execute my program the console is completely empty. I have no idea what is causing this to happen. I am not receiving any error messages except for the "scanner not closed" warning. What is causing this issue?

```
public class BMIprogram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double BMI;
    double weight;
    double height;

    Scanner bodymassScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    weight = bodymassScan.nextInt();
    height = bodymassScan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter weight in pounds: ");
    System.out.println("Enter height in inches: ");

    BMI = ((weight/Math.pow(height, 2)) * 703);

    System.out.println(BMI + " is the BMI");

}
```

}

Comment: You read from the `Scanner` twice before any output. It's waiting for you to give it input.

Comment: @resueman Thanks for the hasty reply. Problem Solved. Have a good weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rearrange your code! The Scanner is waiting for you to make two inputs before printing out the statements.

```
public class BMIprogram {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    double BMI;
    double weight;
    double height;

    Scanner bodymassScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter weight in pounds: ");
    weight = bodymassScan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter height in inches: ");
    height = bodymassScan.nextInt();

    BMI = ((weight/Math.pow(height, 2)) * 703);

    System.out.println(BMI + " is the BMI");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code line order:

```
    System.out.println("Enter weight in pounds: ");
    weight = bodymassScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter height in inches: ");
    height = bodymassScan.nextInt();
```

As the `bodymassScan` is waiting for your input before printing in `System.out`.

Answer (score 0):

Console is empty as it is waiting for your input. When you are executing your code its creating an scanner object and when you are using nextint() method its taking the input using scanner object. After that you are printing "Enter weight in pounds" on console.

Case you want it in proper way you need to rearrange the code like:

```
System.out.println("Enter weight in pounds: ");
weight = bodymassScan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter height in inches: ");
height = bodymassScan.nextInt();
```